# Choose function declaration with lvalue or rvalue parameter

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference, lvalue

Is there a way to remove the 'plumb' version of all of my functions, without the need to change the 'hit' line to the 'fixed'?

Yes my program works fine, but I think if is there a way to get ride from this version of all of my functions.

Keep in mind that `int` is not really `int` in my programs, but a type alias which can be object ( e.g. `container_reference<std::array<double,4>>` ) or reference ( e.g. `std::array<double,4> &` )

```
void func(int &&m) { cout << "rvalue: " << m << endl; }
void func(int  &m) { cout << "lvalue: "; func(std::move(m)); } // PLUMB!

int main() 
{
    int a = 5;
    func(a);    // HIT!
    func(std::move(a)); // FIXED!
    func(6);
    func(a + 5);
}
```

Comment: I feel like you don't really understand, what you are doing. So the question is what are you trying to do? Do you want your `func` to work with rvalues or with lvalues?

Comment: I want to work with both. But the body code is exactly the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm having a bit of trouble understand exactly what you want, but this might be an option:

```
template<typename T>
void func(T &&m) {
  // ...
}
```

`T&&` has been dubbed "universal reference" as it will bind to both lvalues and rvalues due to reference collapsing rules.

Comment: universal reference is available only on template parameters, right?
so `template<typename T> void func<T &&m)` catches everything.
But `void func(int &&m)` catches only rvalues.

Comment: @Chameleon Yes, it requires a deduced type. I accidentally had `auto&&`, but I meant `T&&` here. `auto&&` works elsewhere though, as it's deduced too.